# Windows XP shutdowns automatically

Tags: windows-xp, deep-freeze

I installed 'Deep Freeze' but when I rebooted after installation it didn't show the icon but was still running.

Then I tried to uninstall it but it was showing a message `To uninstall Deep Freeze you need to boot thawed`.

Then I found out that there was a tool which could make Deep Freeze boot thawed I downloaded it then I tried it. It made Deep Freeze boot thawed which was not detected by the Deep Freeze when I tried to uninstall it.

It did make Deep Freeze boot thawed. Then I didn't bother about it, and after 2-3 days my computer started to restart automatically without an error message.

I tried to boot in Safe Mode but that also didn't work. Then I started 'Disable automatic restart on system failure' and it showed me a blue screen with an error message to uninstall any new software and something about my hard drive and then it stated a file `depfrzlo.sys`.

I deleted that file by booting in linux and thought it will work fine but now the error message shows up but no file is stated. Please help me I don't want to format my PC.

Comment: But isn't the point of Deep Freeze to effectively reformat your computer on shutdown?

Comment: @digitxp: No, just to revert to the "freezed" state.

Comment: Deep freeze enables a "non-persistent disk" Think gaming on the NES.  when you hit the reset button your game does not retain any progress or game saves( not to be confused with Zelda for NES)

Answer (score 0):

Normally DeepFreeze can easily be booted unfrozen without a special tool.  However, I have not used DeepFreeze for a while.  At this point you have likley rendered DeepFreeze unusable and a format is likley your best best.  By removing files, it is likley messed up beyond repair.  You might be able to connect the drive to another system to recover files.

DeepFreeze does not "format" but allows the system to remain in a specific state.  USer may be able to install software or malware but a reboot puts the system back to a "known good" state as configured by teh admin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've reformatted by now, but for future reference: you hosed your machine the moment you deleted the file. At that point, Windows still needed the file to function properly, and when you removed (with no way to recover it) you rendered your system worthless.

But that was just the 2nd dumb thing here. The first was downloading a tool claiming to thaw a deep freeze machine. The only tool that can thaw deep freeze is deep freeze. Anything else is an unsupported crack that likely as not brought malware along for the ride.

What you *should* have done is go into your bios and set your system clock ahead by 60 days. That would have been a signal to deep freeze that it should boot thawed. This is the designed way that deep freeze provides for you to signal to a broken installation it should leave things in a state that allows you to fix it.

Not that I expect you to know this, though: it's not very well published by faronics and I only learned the trick recently.